# Is there a powershell function to right click or interact with custom context menus in IE

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, servicenow

I'm trying to write a powershell script that automatically logs into service now (an IT service management tool) and downloads ticket data from their server. To download the data, I need to right click the menu bar at the top of the page and select export > csv in their context menu. I don't have access to their API.

I found out how to log in to ServiceNow through powershell scripting but when I did inspect element to try to figure out how to right click the menu bar and select export > csv and was able to find the id of the button to click but this would only work when the context menu was already pulled up manually.

```
$doc = $ie.Document
$doc.getElementsByClassName("context_item") | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.id -ne $null){
        if($_.id.Contains('d1cd92f20a0a0b3e00b44ff90470380e')){$_.click}
        # the previous line only works when the context menu is already pulled up
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see an auxclick() `$doc.getElementsByClassName("context_item") | gm`. Have you looked at [their REST API](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=madrid&id=c_TableAPI)? [Getting Started](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/catlist/c_GettingStartedWithREST-Container?v=madrid) [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) Alternatively, can you find the exact URL for the resource you want? It might be possible to use [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write a simple query and add it the the URL export feature:

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/newyork-platform-administration/page/administer/exporting-data/task/t_ExportDirectlyFromTheURL.html

This way you can just open the URL and get a .csv back.